# Fan running 100%

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling

Ok so I just bought a new case fan for my computer as a replacement for the stock one as it has surpassed it's life expectancy and began running rather noisily. The installation of this new fan was smooth however once I started the machine, I noticed the fan was running at 100% all the time. This kind of air intake is unnecessary and keeps the fan running at a very loud noise level which is not desirable. I understand it is running at 100% as it has a 3 pin connector so the PWM pin is absent and therefore the machine cannot control the fan speed. I would just accept this and buy a new fan with a 4 pin connector, if it weren't for the fact that the stock fan only had 3 pins and the speed was adjusted relative to the temperature of the machine.

So my question is this: How could both of these fans have 3 pins yet one can adjust the speed while the other cannot?

Comment: I belive the 4th pin isn't necessarily for speed control, but either for more accurate speed control, or possibly monitoring of some sort. I forget exactly what, but the 3 pin should definatly be capable of speed control, otherwise it would be 2 pins. Check that the 3 pins are connected to the same pins as the 1st fan. also check that it's not upside-down

Comment: @Blaine Alrighty thanks for the quick reply, I will crack the case open and have another look and then I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Are you able to see the fan speed from the bios? Please add the model of the motherboard, of the fan and the OS you are using... It can help to find solutions.

Comment: Okay well I could see it in the BIOS however I was not able to change any settings for it.I have an ASRock mobo, an Evercool 80x80x15mm fan and am running Linux Fedora.